# How can I delete a profile photo from Picasa?

Tags: picasa-web-albums

[image]

Picasa has an album of old profile photos I've used. However, clicking a single photo, I can't seem to be able to delete it.

Why is that? How can I delete them?

I used to have Google+, but removed it later on, so these are probably remnants of G+.

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

1. Log on to gmail (email) account.
2. Open a new tab and go to https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/myphotos?noredirect=1
3. Select the "My profile pictures" album
4. Select "Delete album"

I didn't bother to check if individual pictures could be deleted.

It says it takes 24 hours to delete. I couldn't do it from Google+. You can see the photo, press a cross below it to delete it but there is no option to save!